# Table floating overflow inside div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I wonder why **table** element put into **div** goes out of it borders in case it has **float:right** property?

```
<div id="bordered_div">
<p> Some text 1
<p> Some text 2
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Row11</td>
        <td>Row12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row22</td>
        <td>Row21</td>            
    </tr>        
</table>
<div>

#bordered_div {
    border: 1px solid #8c8c8c
}

#myTable {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Please see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uaj67gun/) for clarity

I expect table should be place inside of the bordered area while being floated on it right side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it of course. You just need to put right-floated element before `float:none` elements if you want them to be in one line. So the table should go *before* paragraphs:

```css
#bordered_div {
    border: 1px solid #8c8c8c
}

#myTable {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bordered_div">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Row11</td>
            <td>Row12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row22</td>
            <td>Row21</td>            
        </tr>        
    </table>
    <p> Some text 1
    <p> Some text 2
<div>
```

Comment: Well, yeah, but this is not expected result layout. I want my table be put *after* paragraphs and floated to the right. Is that possible?

Comment: Well the *expected* result is that floated element can't be rendered higher than previous block-level element (`p`). Need to think about possible trick..